# Contact form 7 file php Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, contact-form7

Подскажите, где найти вывод уведомлений в данном плагине? Интересует именно вывод со стороны сервера. Хочу добавить некую разметку к каждому уведомлению

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотря о каких уведомлениях идет речь. Вообще "визуал" осуществляется с помощью js-скрипта contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js. Например, при ошибке в заполнении какого-либо поля появляется span[role="alert"] - это функция wpcf7.notValidTip:

```
wpcf7.notValidTip = function( target, message ) {
    var $target = $( target );
    $( '.wpcf7-not-valid-tip', $target ).remove();
    $( '<span role="alert" class="wpcf7-not-valid-tip"></span>' )
        .text( message ).appendTo( $target );

    if ( $target.is( '.use-floating-validation-tip *' ) ) {
        var fadeOut = function( target ) {
            $( target ).not( ':hidden' ).animate( {
                opacity: 0
            }, 'fast', function() {
                $( this ).css( { 'z-index': -100 } );
            } );
        };

        $target.on( 'mouseover', '.wpcf7-not-valid-tip', function() {
            fadeOut( this );
        } );

        $target.on( 'focus', ':input', function() {
            fadeOut( $( '.wpcf7-not-valid-tip', $target ) );
        } );
    }
};
```

Comment: Я хочу при всех уведомлениях(ошибках, успешной отправке) добавить вконце сообщений кнопочку с крестиком)

Comment: Спрасибо, после добавления классов просто добавил .append()